# Why cache-first strategy is not faster than no service worker?

Tags: javascript, html, service-worker

My web's assets has been set `cache-first` , but load time is much the same as `no service worker` , even more sometimes.

```
// workbox
registerRoute(({ url, event }) => {
  const { href } = url;
  const { request } = event;
  const { destination } = request;

  return assetsPattern.test(href);
}, new CacheFirst({
    cacheName: 'assets-cache',
    plugins: [
      new ExpirationPlugin({
        maxAgeSeconds: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60,
        maxEntries: 100,
      }),
    ],
}))
```

use cache:
[image: use cache]

no cache:
[image: no cache]

Comment: We are lacking your service worker code.

Comment: hmm .. I've written my code

Comment: Lol. I've never seen those plugins. I don't know what is it. Btw cache first fetches everything, but before checks the cache. Cache first is only faster when there no internet connection.

Comment: It's google's Workbox Plugin , Cache first is only faster when no internet , is true ?